# Cant get second hamburger menu to work

Tags: html, css

I was able to get MENU-1 to collapse into a hamburger menu for smaller devices, but cant seem to get MENU-2 to do the same. Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong because i've tried replicating MENU1 codes but to no avail

```css
.cd-auto-hide-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.is-hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo,
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .logo {
  left: 5%;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .logo a, .cd-auto-hide-header .logo img {
  display: block;
}

.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger 
{
  /* vertically align its content */
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #25283D;
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger span
 {
  /* vertically align inside parent element */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before {
  /* this is the menu icon */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em
{
  /* this is the menu central line */
  margin: 6px auto 14px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before, .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::before 
{
  /* this is the menu icon top line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
          transform: translateY(-6px);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger em::after 
{
  /* this is the menu icon bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-auto-hide-header .nav-trigger 
 {
    display: none;
  }
}

.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em 
{
  /* transform menu icon into a 'X' icon */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::before 
{
  /* rotate top line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.cd-auto-hide-header.nav-open .nav-trigger em::after 
{
  /* rotate bottom line */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cd-primary-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul a {
  /* target primary-nav links */
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  color: #25283D;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.cd-primary-nav > ul a:hover, .cd-primary-nav > ul a.active {
  color: #8F3985;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-primary-nav {
    /* vertically align its content */
    display: table;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul {
    /* vertically align inside parent element */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* reset mobile style */
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav > ul a {
    /* reset mobile style */
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}

.nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
.cd-primary-nav ul:target {
  /* 
   show primary nav - mobile only 
   :target is used to show navigation on no-js devices
  */
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-open .cd-primary-nav ul,
  .cd-primary-nav ul:target {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

2. Auto-Hiding Navigation - with Sub Nav

-------------------------------- */
.cd-secondary-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #25283D;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
}
.cd-secondary-nav::after {
  /* gradient on the right - to indicate it's possible to scroll */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  background: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #25283D, rgba(37, 40, 61, 0));
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
.cd-secondary-nav.nav-end::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul, .cd-secondary-nav li, .cd-secondary-nav a {
  height: 100%;
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul {
 
}
.cd-secondary-nav ul::after {
clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.cd-secondary-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /* do not shrink - elements float on the right of the element */
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
}
.cd-secondary-nav li:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.cd-secondary-nav a {
  display: block;
  
  opacity: .6;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.cd-secondary-nav a:hover, .cd-secondary-nav a.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav ul {
    /* reset mobile style */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav li {
    /* reset mobile style */
    float: none;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
        -ms-flex-negative: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a {
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav a.active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #8F3985;
  }
}





.cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}
.cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
          transform: translateY(-60px);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-secondary-nav.fixed {
    top: 80px;
    
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 #25283D;
  }
  .cd-secondary-nav.slide-up {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-80px);
            transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="cd-auto-hide-header">
 <div class="logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>

 <nav class="cd-primary-nav">
  <a href="#cd-navigation" class="nav-trigger">
   <span>
    <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
    MENU-1
   </span>
  </a> <!-- .nav-trigger -->

  <ul id="cd-navigation">
   <li><a href="#0">The team</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">Our Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">Our Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">Shopping tools</a></li>
   <li><a href="#0">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav> <!-- .cd-primary-nav -->
</header> <!-- .cd-auto-hide-header -->

  
  
  <section class="cd-hero">
 <div class="cd-hero-content">
  <!-- your content here -->
 </div>
  </section> <!-- .cd-hero -->
  
  
<nav class="cd-secondary-nav">
<span>
 <em aria-hidden="true"></em>
  MENU-2
</span>

 <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#0">Intro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Photos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Specs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Compare</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Buy</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav> <!-- .cd-secondary-nav -->
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a simplified version of this in a jsFiddle instead of using your production code. All of that -webkit- and otherwise - prefixed code is clouding things. The main problem is that you have a bunch of confusing code you got somewhere, and you don't fully understand it. If you can break it down into something more simple, it will start to make more sense for you - and for us. You can look at this for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dej01Luy/   : )

Comment: @shriffderek, it's 2 auto hide headers, so all that "production" is necessary. my problem is, i cant seem to get the second header to follow the first and collapse into a hamburger menu on smaller devices rather than having a scroll bar appear.